# Obtaining or subsetting the first 5 minutes of each day of data from an xts

Tags: r, time-series, subset, xts

I would like to subset out the first 5 minutes of time series data for each day from minutely data, however the first 5 minutes do not occur at the same time each day thus using something like `xtsobj["T09:00/T09:05"]` would not work since the beginning of the first 5 minutes changes. i.e. sometimes it starts at 9:20am or some other random time in the morning instead of 9am.

So far, I have been able to subset out the first minute for each day using a function like:

```
k <- diff(index(xtsobj))> 10000

xtsobj[c(1, which(k)+1)]
```

i.e. finding gaps in the data that are larger than 10000 seconds, but going from that to finding the first 5 minutes of each day is proving more difficult as the data is not always evenly spaced out. I.e. between first minute and 5th minute there could be from 2 row to 5 rows and thus using something like:

```
xtsobj[c(1, which(k)+6)]
```

and then binding the results together

is not always accurate. I was hoping that a function like 'first' could be used, but wasn't sure how to do this for multiple days, perhaps this might be the optimal solution. Is there a better way of obtaining this information?

Many thanks for the stackoverflow community in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split(xtsobj, "days")` will create a list with an xts object for each day.

Then you can apply `head` to the each day

```
lapply(split(xtsobj, "days"), head, 5)
```

or more generally

```
lapply(split(xtsobj, "days"), function(x) {
  x[1:5, ]
})
```

Finally, you can `rbind` the days back together if you want.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(xtsobj, "days"), function(x) x[1:5, ]))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about you use the package `lubridate`, first find out the starting point each day that according to you changes sort of randomly, and then use the function `minutes`

So it would be something like:

```
five_minutes_after = starting_point_each_day + minutes(5)
```

Then you can use the usual subset of `xts` doing something like:

```
5_min_period = paste(starting_point_each_day,five_minutes_after,sep='/')

xtsobj[5_min_period]
```

Edit:

@Joshua
I think this works, look at this example:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- xts(cumsum(rnorm(20, 0, 0.1)), Sys.time() - seq(60,1200,60))

starting_point_each_day= index(x[1])
five_minutes_after = index(x[1]) + minutes(5)
five_min_period = paste(starting_point_each_day,five_minutes_after,sep='/')

x[five_min_period]
```

In my previous example I made a mistake, I put the five_min_period between quotes.
Was that what you were pointing out Joshua? Also maybe the starting point is not necessary, just:

```
until5min=paste('/',five_minutes_after,sep="")
x[until5min]
```

Comment: `xtsobj['5_min_period']` won't work.  You can only subset xts objects with very specific types of strings.

Comment: I said `xtsobj['5_min_period']` won't work because `'5_min_period'` is not a string xts will recognize.  Glad you corrected the mistake.

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaUlrich for your comment and particularly for developing a very useful package.